# Combine laravel resource and singleton in route

Tags: php, laravel

I really clueless now. For the new updated laravel, laravel provides singleton that have one and only one instance in the application. Is it possible to have singleton for only particular class like edit and the rest is normal as usual

I do like this in the web.php but i lose access to edit page. I can only browse others but not edit page.

```
Route::resource('manageprofile', DvinfoController::class)
        ->except('edit');
Route::singleton('manageprofile', DvinfoController::class)
        ->only('edit');
```

Need help from expert

Comment: Why are you using the same route and class for both?

Comment: I just follow the documentation from laravel

Comment: a resource either fits the concept of a 'singleton' (in these new routing terms) or it doesn't ... it is either a resource that contains 0 or many or it is a resource that can only contain 1 (those 2 options have different numbers of routes defined)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use the singleton method on a single route in Laravel. The singleton method is used to bind a class or interface to a single instance within the container, so that every time the class or interface is resolved, the same instance is returned.

If you want to use a single instance of a controller for only some of the routes in your application, you can create a new route group and apply the singleton method to the group like this:

```
Route::singleton('manageprofile', DvinfoController::class)
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('manageprofile/edit', 'DvinfoController@edit')->name('manageprofile.edit');
        Route::put('manageprofile/{id}', 'DvinfoController@update')->name('manageprofile.update');
    });

Route::resource('manageprofile', DvinfoController::class)
    ->except('edit');
```

This way, the edit and update routes will use a single instance of the DvinfoController class, while the rest of the routes in the manageprofile resource will use a new instance of the controller.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#singleton-resource-controllers

Comment: I got an error 'Method Illuminate\Routing\PendingSingletonResourceRegistration::group does not exist.' when using group.